# Excel VBA Rounding

Tags: excel, rounding, vba

I am trying to use the following code to replace each cell within a selected range with the rounded number of the cell within that range but I continue to get an error.

```
Sub add_round()
Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        rng.Value = Round(rng.Value, -4)
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think it makes sense to have -4 places after the decimal point? What are you hoping to do?

Comment: The `Round()`  function can't receive a negative value for the decimal positions. I think that you're trying to round to a closest power of ten

Comment: Can you show a before and after ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to make this function yourself, as follows (I'm not aware of a function in VBA which works as Excel's native Round function, which allows you to round to the nearest 1000 etc):

```
Sub add_round()

Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        rng.Value = Round(rng.Value / 10000, 0) * 10000
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Alternatively you can tell VBA to use the native Excel function like this:

```
Sub add_round()

Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(rng.Value, - 4)
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: @KatR Glad I could help - if this answered your question then don't forget to click 'answered' next to this answer's score.